# Expressions in Databinding... possible? How to?

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7

I have a collection databound to a `ListBox`.  What I would like to do is show some UI based on whether or not some property of the member of the collection exists.

E.g.:

```
public class Widget
{
  public string foo;
  public string bar;
}

public ObservableCollection<Widget> Stuff;
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding foo}" 
                 Visiblity="{Binding 
                   (foo != null ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed)
                 }"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Note the `Visibility` attribute on the `TextBlock`.  Clearly this isn't supported, but it should give you an idea of what I want to do.

One possible solution is that I could add a property to widget that looks like this:

```
public Visibility has_foo;
```

And then:

```
... Visibility="{Binding has_foo}" ...
```

But it seems awkward to have to generate these additional properties.

I suspect there is a much better way.  Is there?  How would you do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a value converter. Something like

```
public class NullToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then add it something like

```
<YourUserControl.Resources>
   <NullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVisibilityConverter" />
</YourUserControl.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding foo}" 
                 Visiblity="{Binding foo, 
                     Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Obviously I've not implemented ConvertBack (not really sure if you will be able to convert back) but you shouldn't need it in this instance.

Comment: Brilliant!  I knew there was something happy like that, I just didn't know what to look for.  Thanks; I'll give this a try.

Comment: IValueConverter has some serious performance issues in WP7 OS.
ref: PDC 2010 Windows phone 7 session